# in selenium ide, how to verify if date is equal to 'current date plus 2 working days(Mon- Fri)

Tags: date, ide, selenium

in selenium ide, how to verify if date is equal to 'current date plus 2 business days(Mon- Fri).

I have to verify this against our app, i have the below code which checks if the date is current date + 2 days but i need to get 2 working days .

```
javascript{ "0" + ((new Date()).getMonth()+1)+'/'+((new Date()).getDate()+2)+'/'+(new Date()).getFullYear()}
```

I know how to get this done in rc but wondering if this can be done in selenium ide.

Thanks.